# Where are the default ViewControllers names from?

Tags: ios, xcode, ide, viewcontroller

I started an app using the **tabbed template**: it features two ViewControllers, First and Second. I can see their names in the scenes inspector on the left (see image below).

Now: if I add a new ViewController to the Storyboard (and to the tab controller, of course), I must provide a title for its name to show on the left.

Strangely enough, I can't see any title for the First and Second ViewController (default).

[image]

Where are their names from?

Comment: you want to add another item to tabbar controller ?

Comment: I added it, my question was different: the custom viewController needs a title to be set, while the tabbed bar app template features two viewControllers whose title field is empty (as you can see on the right of the image)

Comment: In the above your "Second" is the name of the view controller that you selected

Comment: My question is: where is that name from if on the right side the title is empty? If I create a new viewController, to set its name where you see that "Second" I must fill the text field you see on the right of the image, where you see "Title"

Comment: It comes from the tabbar item name asteric in the picture. If you want to change the view controller as  a different name just fill up the blank "Title" its simple

Answer (score 1):

You can set it when inspecting tab bar item on each of the view controllers. See attached image.
[image]

Example: [image]

Comment: That one is the name of the bar item, not the viewcontrollers'

Comment: @3000 Changing this name, will change the scene and view controller name. You can see an example of this on the second screenshot. Or is it still not what you mean?

Comment: In my XCode, changing that title doesn't change the VC name on the left   :-)

Comment: Well, you may need to close and reopen the `storyboard` file :] It's Xcode after all.

Comment: HAHAHA, it's the same action taken by my grandpa when the tv didn't work  :-D